# How to get UI Bezier path pathsArray from an Image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, uibezierpath

I have implemented uiBezier path implementation to draw paint strokes, like this

```
{
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.tempDrawImage.bounds.size);

        for ( NSDictionary *dict in pathsArray )
        {
            UIBezierPath *p ;
            @try {
                p = (UIBezierPath*)[dict objectForKey:@"path"];
            }
            @catch (NSException *exception) {
                continue;
            }


            p.lineWidth = [[dict objectForKey:@"size"]floatValue];

                CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeCopy);
                [[UIColor colorWithRed:[[dict objectForKey:@"red"]floatValue]
                                 green:[[dict objectForKey:@"green"]floatValue]
                                  blue:[[dict objectForKey:@"blue"]floatValue]
                                 alpha:[[dict objectForKey:@"alpha"]floatValue]] setStroke];

            [p stroke];
        }

        [[UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:opacity] setStroke];

        if(isEraser) //When eraser selected, change color as clear
        {
            CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeClear);
        }
        else
        {
            CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeCopy);
        }

            [bzierPath stroke];

        self.tempDrawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

}
```

But **I need to get the Bezier path or PathsArray- Dict format *`from the existing image`* is it possible..?**

i need to use it as part of my app.

i do an app for photo editing,

In the original image im making paint stroke, in this i maintained Undo Redi Stack,

after done paint, and then do operation like remove/cut painted place, and then do same thing like this..

All these operations should be in Undo redo stack..

Comment: Why do you need to do that? It will not be easy (though it is technically possible). Is this a one time requirement?

Comment: It will be used as part of my app.. see my edited wuestion for  my requiremet

Comment: You want to offer infinite undo? You can't do that by converting a final image into vector paths...